# How to prevent caching (force image reload) wtih PHP and JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, image, caching, refresh

I tried these two method to prevent caching (force image reload) wtih PHP and JavaScript/jQuery, but I still get the image from the cache when I load the content through ajax,

PHP:

```
 // Generate a number that will never be repeated using the time function 
 // that "returns the current time measured in the number of seconds since 
 // the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT)"
 $cachekiller = time();

 // Include the generated number in the image URL
 <img src="path/to/image.png?{$cachekiller}"
```

Javascript/ jquery:

```
// Generate random number between 1 and 1000.
var cachekiller = Math.floor(Math.random()*1001);

$("#thumbnail").attr("src", "path/to/image.png?"+cachekiller);
```

What else can I do?

Comment: This should not be cached because the URL to get it is unique each time.  How are you determining that it is cached?

Comment: What do you mean, through ajax?

Comment: What cache headers are you sending with the image?

Comment: Hi guys - I meant the image size changes frequently in the server and I want to reload it through ajax.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the image changes frequently in the server and you want to reload it through ajax. If that is the case, adding a random number to the URL will not help. This is because, servers do not apply cache control for resources based on URL. They use the "If-Modified-Since" parameter in the request headers for cache control. Refer [this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/caching.html). You can try setting the If-Modified-Since header in the request to a past time and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks. Yes - the image size changes frequently in the server and I want to reload it through ajax.